# Exclude specific URL from Tomcat ExpiresFilter Cache

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to exclude a single specific URL from the Tomcat Expires Filter, so that it is not cached by the client Browser?

The file Content-Type is text/javascript (as seen in the browser), compressed as gzip.

It is important that all remaining Javascript files remain cacheable.

This is the default expires filter:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 7 day</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ...
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the new Expires Filter I tried to ***add in addition*** to the default Filter:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>SecondaryExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresByType text/javascript</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 1 second</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>SecondaryExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/js/session.jsp</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The specified request continues to come back with:

```
cache-control   
"max-age=604800"
```

I also tried the following types:

`application/javascript`

`text/javascript;charset=UTF-8`

The latter should, according to the docs, take precedence over the less specific `text/javascript`

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter

Comment: I think through the code it is possible. Once I did with the code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to write your own class which `extends ExpiresFilter` and override the `isEligibleToExpirationHeaderGeneration` method, like this:

```
@Override
protected boolean isEligibleToExpirationHeaderGeneration(
        HttpServletRequest request, XHttpServletResponse response) {
    if("/my/special/uri".equals(request.getRequestURI())) {
        return false; // Don't do any Expires stuff
    } else {
        return super.isEligibleToExpirationHeaderGeneration(request, response);
    }
}
```